# How to navigate into an Ionic 2 app

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, nav, ionic2, viewchild

I'm trying to do a small app in Ionic 2 but I can't manage to navigate...
I have read the documentation, navigation stuff, navController, some post on StackOverflow... I tried for hours but I'm stuck ! I had several issues.

I had to find a way to use `navController` into my app.js, which I did thanks to `@viewChild` and StackOF. I don't fully understand the principle.
I set `rootPage: any = Login;`. As I have a menu on my app, I disabled it on this page. On a button `(click)`, I set the root `this.nav.setRoot()` with `HomePage`.
Now from the HomePage, within the menu, I want to navigate through some pages. I'm stuck here. I used the `(click)="openPage(Messagerie)"` method.
First issue, the parameter in openPage() is undefined. Then I tried the `[navPush]="pageMessagerie"` and `this.pageMessagerie = Messagerie;` method following the documentation, but it didn't works as well, nothing happen. So, I tried to hard-code the page into my openPage() function : `this.nav.push(Messagerie);`. Here I have another issue again. The first time I call the push(), the page seems to appear and disappear immediately, coming back on the HomePage. The second time I click, it seems to work. I can go on the Messagerie page and come back on the HomePage via the back button on the navbar.

So... Here I am, stuck with the navigation ! I don't know what to do.
Here is my code.

---

**Update**
Ok the undefined is ok now. But my nav still act weird. When I use `this.nav.push()` on the home page I got this workflow : 
Click on Messagerie : Open Messagerie and immediately back on Home Page.
Click on Demandes : Open Messagerie, immediately Demandes and stay there.
Click on navbar back button : Back to Messagerie, back to Demandes and back to Home Page. Of course if I use `this.nav.setRoot()` each time it works but I lose the nav principle.

---

**App.html**

```
<ion-menu [content]="content">
    <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-title>Menu</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
    <ion-content>
        <ion-list>
            <button ion-item menuToggle = "left">
                Mes informations
            </button>
            <button ion-item menuToggle = "left" (click)="openPage(Messagerie)">
                Ma messagerie
            </button>
            <button ion-item menuToggle = "left" (click)="openPage(Demandes)">
                Mes demandes
            </button>
        </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
</ion-menu>

<ion-nav id="nav" #content [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>
```

**App.ts**

```
import {Component, ViewChild}  from '@angular/core';
import {Platform, ionicBootstrap, NavController} from 'ionic-angular';
import {StatusBar}  from 'ionic-native';
import {HomePage}   from './pages/home/home';
import {Messagerie} from './pages/messagerie/messagerie';
import {Demandes}   from './pages/demandes/demandes';
import {Login}      from './pages/login/login';

@Component({
    templateUrl: 'build/app.html' 
})

export class MyApp {

    @ViewChild('content') nav

    rootPage: any = Login;

    constructor(private platform: Platform) {
        platform.ready().then(() => {
            StatusBar.styleDefault();
        });
    }

    openPage(page) {
        console.log(page);
        this.nav.push(page);
    }
}

ionicBootstrap(MyApp);
```

**Login.ts** (with the setroot)

```
import {Component}      from '@angular/core';
import {NavController, MenuController}  from 'ionic-angular';
import {FormBuilder, ControlGroup, Validators} from '@angular/common';
import {HomePage}       from '../home/home';

@Component({
    selector: 'mc-login',
    templateUrl: 'build/pages/login/login.html'
})
export class Login {

    loginForm: ControlGroup;

    loginChanged:       boolean = false;
    motdepasseChanged:  boolean = false;
    submitAttempt:      boolean = false;

    constructor(private nav: NavController, private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private menu: MenuController) {
        this.menu.enable(false);
        this.loginForm = formBuilder.group({
            login: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.maxLength(10), Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z ]*'), Validators.required])],
            motdepasse: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.maxLength(10), Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z ]*'), Validators.required])]
        });
    }

    elementChanged(input) {
        let field = input.inputControl.name;
        this[field+"Changed"] = true;
    }

    logintoapp() {
        this.submitAttempt = true;

        if(this.loginForm.valid) {
            this.logindatabase();
        } else {
            console.log("Nope");
        }    
    }

    logindatabase() {
        this.nav.setRoot(HomePage);
    }
}
```

Do I miss something ? What am I doing wrong ?
Thanks a lot for your help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you try this:

In app.ts, declare the nav and following array as following:

```
@ViewChild(Nav) nav:Nav;

browsePages:Array<{title:string, component:any}>;
```

add to your constructor (this is just need to explicitly close the menu later):

```
private menu: MenuController
```

inside your constructor declare your pages you want to add to your menu:

```
this.browsePages = [
        {title: 'Ma messagerie', component: Messagerie},
        {title: 'Mes demandes', component: Demandes}
    ];
```

replace your buttons "Ma messagerie" et "Mes demandes" in html like following:

```
<button ion-item *ngFor="let p of browsePages" (click)="openPage(p)">
   {{p.title}}
</button>
```

and then finally your openPage method:

```
openPage(page) {
    // close the menu when clicking a link from the menu
    this.menu.close();
    // navigate to the new page if it is not the current page
    this.nav.setRoot(page.component);
}
```

That was for the navigation from the menu.

Now about the navigation from the login page...replace your setroot with a navigation push. Generally speaking, except when you really need to set the root you should, I think, push pages in the stack to navigate not set the root again. So basically use push and pop on the navcontroller to navigate.

*** UPDATE to go to the next page and removing current one from history

```
logindatabase() {
    this.goToNextPageWithoutBack(HomePage);
}

private goToNextPageWithoutBack(page:any, params?:any) {
    this.nav.push(page, params).then(() => {
        this.removeCurrentViewFromHistory();
    });
}

private removeCurrentViewFromHistory() {
    const index = this.nav.getActive().index;
    this.nav.remove(0, index);
}
```

**** UPDATE

And then to display the menu toggle in your homepage.html add

```
<ion-header>
<ion-navbar>

<button menuToggle start>
  <ion-icon name="ios-menu-outline"></ion-icon>
</button>

<ion-title>my-items</ion-title>
</ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

I tried to extract these lines from my working codes, hope it gonna help you.

Comment: Thanks for all those advices to clean my code @Peter ! But when I use `push` instead of `setRoot`, I arrive on the HomePage with a navbar with a back arrow, and not the menu button... It's not my main page any more. 
And as I said to @tothefux, I still have issues with the workflow of the navigation. Please check my comment on his answer.
Actually... If I use setRoot on every pageOpen(), it works, but it's not the solution, I loose the workflow.

Comment: You are right, after a "push" you will land on a page where the "back" button will be displayed in the navigation. If you want to land on a next page without having the possibility to go back you could just remove the last page from the history. I edited my solution. This is the solution I implemented to solve the "Login / Homepage" in my app, don't know if it is the best but it does the job.

Comment: Your update works well thanks @Peter, except I can't declare `@ViewChild(Nav) nav:Nav;` : _Cannont find 'Nav'_. And that `@ViewChild('Nav') nav:'Nav';` : _Error TS2339: Property 'setRoot' does not exist on type '"Nav"'_. So I stay with `@ViewChild('content') nav;`

Actually I want to use the push() method, not necessarily from home page to Messagerie (Inbox), but from Inbox to the message itself for example. And it doesn't work. I have a weird workflow :
Click Messagerie = Messagerie, auto back on HomePage.
Click Demandes = Demandes.
Click Back Button = Messagerie then HomePage.

Comment: Cool to hear that did the job for that part. I guess with push, goToNextPageWithoutBack and pop you could do your first flow. The second flow is more tricky since you want to achieve a kind of special "back" right? so in that maybe two idea, the first is to take care by yourself about the view in the stack and remove the one you don't want (you could iterate thru the nav stack and remove for example the index you don't want or the instanceof the page you don't want) or another idea is to implement your own back button on the view you want (calling a push action). Does that help?

Comment: No no, @Peter, no special back feature ! I uploaded my app on GitHub. https://github.com/Xav20/Xav20 Just try to navigate, you will see the problem. Well if you want of course !

Comment: I had a look quite a long time at your code and found different mistakes, I think. 1. in method openPage(page) you forget to push the component, not the all key value (page.component instead of just page). 2. If you didn't find 'Nav' in your app.ts it's because you forgot to import it. 3. In all your pages component, delete "selector: ". If you would I could send you the files. Not solve your navigation problem, but it's just then a question of adjustment I think (playing with push and pop)

Comment: I resolved my strange navigation issue ! It's because my pages use `@Component` decorator instead of `@Page` ! The NavController doesn't work without @Page ! I will do another post tomorrow. Thanks a lot for your help ! I'll eddit this post tomorrow as well. Thanks again @Peter for your time !

Comment: Great game, congratulations!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your scope variables to the actual pages. Right now the (click)="openPage(Messagerie)" --> Messagerie being passed in is undefined. You need to set this.Messagerie = Messagerie in your component.

Comment: Thanks @tothefux ! It solves the issue with the undefined. I still have problems with the workflow into the nav.
When I click on Messagerie, it goes to Messagerie and come back on HomePage immediatly. I click again, it stays on Messagerie, but when I hit the back button on the nav I pass two time by Messagerie. Then I click on Demandes, ok, back, I go by Messagerie and HomePage...

`1) "Messagerie" = Messagerie -> HomePage
2) "Demandes" = Demandes. 
3) "Back Button" = Messagerie -> HomePage`

Comment: Ah man that is not cool. What version of Ionic 2 are you running?

Comment: I use Ionic 2 beta10. I really don't understand why the nav does that. I read the doc, examples, it seems to work that way, but it doesn't. Yet it should be simple ! It's just push and pop into the nav... Is it possible that there is a issue with the nav / rootNav / viewChild or something ? 
When I use setRoot() everywhere of course it works, but there is no more management of the navigation.